# Azure Functions Host Instance vs VM Instance

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there a difference between Host Instance and VM instance when running an Azure Functions on a Dedicated App Service Plan? Because according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan), App Service Plan use existing VM instances. But in my Function App's Scale Out plan, I can see option to increase the instance count. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan), it says that scaling will add new VM instance. But according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-and-premium-plans-work), a host instance is the full Function App instance.

So, will increasing the instance count, spin up new VM instance under the App Service Plan? If not, then is that going to start a new function app instance on same VM instance if possible? Does Scaling mean different for different plans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider them as the same thing.

> will increasing the instance count, spin up new VM instance under the
> App Service Plan?

Yes, it will add one or more new VM instances under the App Service Plan. For [Dedicated (App Service) plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan) in azure function, we always need to manually scale out/in because in azure function it does not dynamically add/remove new compute resources. But for the other 2 plans, they dynamically add/remove compute resources.

> If not, then is that going to start a new function app instance on
> same VM instance if possible?

no, the new instance will be added in the newly added VM instance.

> Does Scaling mean different for different plans?

The only difference of scaling for these plans like this:

**For** [Consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan) or [Premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan), it `scales out/in` automatically based on the number of incoming events, and they don't support the `scale up` feature.

**For** [Dedicated (App Service) plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan), it both supports `scale out/in` and `scale up`, but you need to manually do that.

Hope it helps. And also let me know if you still have more issues about that.

Comment: But Dedicated App Service plan has a custom auto-scale feature too which can scale out based on some specified metric.

Comment: If multiple function apps are using the same App Service plan, does that mean actual app instances are using same VM resources?

Comment: @AsifulNobel, **for the first question**, I think the term "auto" confuses you. when using the other 2 plans, you don't need to do any configuration manually to scale out/in; but for  Dedicated App Service plan, you need to manually configure the auto-scale feature, right?   **For the second one**, yes, they will share the same VM resources.

Comment: Yes, I have not use the other two plans. So, I was not aware of this. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanYang Isn't scale up available in a Premium plan? I can see the option to upgrade EP1 => EP2/EP3 in the Portal.